# Azure AD B2C API connectors User Attributs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am in the process of setting up Azure AD B2C and including an API connector in the profile creation. I use the policy Sign up and sign in from the user flows. Now I want to add a user attribute I created myself. This should not be visible under User attributes (the user should not fill this field himself) but should be filled by the API and returned under Application Claims and in the token. Is this possible with the user flows? Or is this currently only possible with the Custom policies under Identity Experience Framework?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this with Azure AD B2C user flows would be to use JavaScript to hide the field so that is not visible to the user even though it is selected as an attribute in the user flow.

A similar approach is user to enable captcha while signing up as well in this sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-sign-up-user-flow-captcha.

Here is the official documentation for using JavaScript in user flows - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
If I see it correctly, there is no possibility to set default values for the fields (The fields are not displayed to the user)?
The only possibility then is JavaScript or Custom Policies.

Comment: Yes. Since you need a hidden field while signing up, the only way to do it is Javascript. If you don’t want to use Javascript, you will need to use custom policies.